# logging exceptions

Tags: c#, logging

i built an object to count and log errors. I write the log after a timer elapsed. I don't know how many errors will occur each log period, so i set the List _lastReadErrors to a maximum of 5 errors. In the Full implementation i would like to log some more errors. The logging object should use as less memory as possible. If i put 30 strings in the List, would it make a big difference?

```cs
public static class Monitor
{
    private static object _syncRoot = new object();

    private static DateTime _monitorStart;

    private static Timer _logTimer;

    private static int _readErrorsAbsolute;

    private static List<string> _lastReadErrors;

    public Monitor()
    {
        _monitorStart = DateTime.Now;
        _logTimer = new Timer();

        _readErrorsAbsolute = 0;

        _readErrors = new List<string>();

        _logTimer.Elapsed += writeLog;
        _logTimer.Interval = 3600000;
        _logTimer.AutoReset = true;
        _logTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    public DateTime MonitorStart
    {
        get { return _monitorStart; }
    }

    public int ReadErrorsAbsolute
    {
        get { return _readErrorsAbsolute; }
    }

    public void ReadError(Exception ex)
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref _readErrorsAbsolute);

        lock (_syncRoot)
        {
            if (_lastReadErrors.Count > 4) _lastReadErrors.RemoveAt(0);
            _lastReadErrors.Add(ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }

    private void writeLog(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        string logString = buildLogString();

        // write the logstring into a memorystream

        _monitorStart = DateTime.Now;

        _readErrorsAbsolute = 0;

        lock (_syncRoot)
        {    
             _readErrors = new List<string>();
        }
    }

    private string buildLogString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append("Date: " + _monitorStart.ToString() + " Errors: " + _readErrorsAbsolute.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);

        lock (_syncRoot)
        {
            foreach (string error in _lastReadErrors)
            {
                sb.Append(error + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: "If I put 30 strings in the List, would it make a big difference?" Depends a lot on how big the strings are!

Comment: Take a look at NLog or log4net. Those are very configurable and you can add logging levels.

Comment: @Luuk log4net or other log appenders are not an option, i only can use trusted assemblies and all the stuff around won't be trusted :-(.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Who knows how long ex.StackTrace could be? Any experiences?

Comment: At least 1K, (we've had errors logging them in a 1K database field).

Comment: Why not write them directly to the MemoryStream using an StringWriter (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringwriter.aspx)